# How to obtain continuity of context between adjacent Zeppelin cells

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

As seen in the following `zeppelin` notebook we have two cells:

- First cell performs an operation and saves the result in the `out` variable
- Second cell attempts to perform an operation on the `out` variable.  Instead there is an error indicating that the cell ***does not even realize it should be running pyspark***

[image]

So -unlike `jupyter/ipython notebook` - it seems that Zeppelin has no continuity between cells : each cell is completely independent?  That is seriously limiting: we want to divide the work into chunks and run the chunks one at a time .. like in `Jupyter` ..

So am I missing something about how to "link" cells together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each paragraph (the same as cell in jupyter) can use different technology. Those are supported in Zeppelin called intepreter. And is because of this make Zeppelin convinient.

#### Assume like this use case.

- Describe a Notebook with Markdown
- Preprare the data with Shell, like curl, cp
- Analyse with Spark
- Some analyze with SQL using Spark with a temp table
- Publish result file with Shell

#### Scope

Environment are shared directly by the same intepreter in the same notebook. Which means.

> In the **SAME** type of Interpreter, Variables/Method/Classes defined in one paragraph **CAN** be used by paragraphs **executed later**. It does not have to be physically later, just need be executed later.
>
> In the **DIFFERENT** type of Interpreter,  Variables/Method/Classes defined in one paragraph **CAN NOT** be used by paragraphs executed later.
>
> Between different interpreters, Variables/Method/Classes are not directly visible. [Backend Angular API](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/displaysystem/back-end-angular.html) can be used to pass between different interpreters.
>
> Between Spark and Pyspark, temp tables are visiable to each other.

#### Default interpreter.

- One notebook can have one default interpreter.
- Other interpreter to be used shall be explicitly using % notation.

#### Example

Here is an example.
[image]

Comment: It might have been true at some point that variables could not be accessed across cells and languages, but [it is no longer true](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/dynamicform.html).  (That link is simply to an example, not API docs.)